# Centering flex items on wrap with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have the following code with Bootstrap 4.
There's a right item and several items located on the left:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| item 1 item 2 item 3                                   Right item |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When the screen becomes too small I would like them to be like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|            item 1 item 2 item 3           |
|                 Right item                |
---------------------------------------------
```

This is almost what is happening...
But instead I get:

```
---------------------------------------------
| item 1 item 2 item 3                       |
| Right item                                 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Here's the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gax5n8qa/3/

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Center with flexbox only on smaller screen widths...

This way doesn't require using the grid, or adding extra classes to the child divs...

https://www.codeply.com/go/85w4qy1iIB

```
<container class="my-class 
                  d-flex 
                  align-items-center 
                  justify-content-center
                  justify-content-sm-between
                  flex-sm-row
                  flex-column
                  px-2">
    <div>
        <a class="pr-2">Item 1</a>
        <a class="px-2">Item 2</a>
        <a class="pl-2">Item 3</a>
    </div>
    <div>Right Item</div>
</container>
```

This works by using the [**flexbox utils**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) responsively...

- `justify-content-center` - align horizontal center on xs (implied breakpoint)
- `justify-content-sm-between` - space between on sm and up
- `flex-sm-row` - direction row on sm and up
- `flex-column` - direction column (stacked) on xs

Answer (score 4):

Use mr-auto and justify-content-center to container div.Resize the screen to check in both fiddle and snippet

```css
.my-class {
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<Container class="my-class 
                  d-flex 
                  flex-wrap
                  align-items-center justify-content-center">
                  
                  
  
  
  <div class="col-auto mr-auto">
    <a class="pr-2">Item 1</a>
    <a class="px-2">Item 2</a>
    <a class="pl-2">Item 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">Right Item</div>
  
</Container>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/gax5n8qa/33/

Answer (score 2):

Use [grid breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) for column and [text alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment) with grid breakpoints to set the desired behavior on small screens.

```
<Container class="my-class 
                  d-flex 
                  align-items-center
                  flex-wrap
                  px-2">
  <div class="col-12 text-center col-md text-md-left">
    <a class="pr-2">Item 1</a>
    <a class="px-2">Item 2</a>
    <a class="pl-2">Item 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 text-center col-md d-md-flex align-items-end flex-column">Right Item</div>
</Container>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fyKU8sINmi